# Data operations (fill, min, max) on CSV data in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, csv, data-visualization, interpolation

I'm loading different indicator CSV files into JavaScript, example:

```
CSV for population:

id,year,value
AF,1800,3280000
AF,1820,3280000
AF,1870,4207000
AG,1800,37000
AG,1851,37000
AG,1861,37000
```

For each indicator file I need to:

- Gap fill missing years for each entity (id)
- Find the time span for each entity
- Find the min and max for each entity
- Find the time span for the indicator
- Find the min and max for the indicator

**What is an inexpensive way of performing these operations? Alternatively, is there a good JavaScript library for performing these kind of common data operations and storing the data effectively in various object representations?**

I'd like the final representation of the above file to look something like:

```
data = {
    population : {
        entities : 
            AF : {
                data : {
                    1800 : 3280000,
                    1801 : 3280000,
                 },
                entity_meta : {
                    start : 1800,
                    end : 
                    min : 
                    max :
             },
            [...]
        indicator_meta : {
                start : 1700,
                end : 
                min : 
                max :
        }
        [...]
```

Thanks!

Comment: There are a few common data operations, yes, but if you want 'inexpensive' way of operating JS data in term of performance/resource, library is usually the bad answer. Library make development faster, but rarely run faster. So, do you want neat code or do you want fast code?

Comment: @Sheepy: You're right. I basically want a few simple functions that, once the csv file has been loaded, effectively traverses the entities and do the entity-level calculations. Once this is done, it can do the indicator-level summary. Fast rather than neat, as long as it can read the input format and output the correct structure :)

Comment: Before we goes into full-sample-code mode, one more question: how are you passing the csv into JS, is that part of the question?
e.g. Do you read the csv in server-side processing, from ajax, or let user select from local files?

Comment: @Sheepy: Right now I'm reading one indicator file at a time (on user request), using d3.csv: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv. I  can then do some nesting operations etc. to come up with the above output. The data operations can surely be faster though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets Assume that you have the CSV data in a 2d array:

```
var data = [[AF,1800,3280000],
[AF,1820,3280000],
[AF,1870,4207000],
[AG,1800,37000],
[AG,1851,37000],
[AG,1861,37000]]
```

For this example I will use jQuerys utility functions as it will make the job a lot easier without any real overhead.

```
// we will loop thru all the rows
// if the id does not belong to the entities then we will add the property.
// if the property does exist then we update the values

var entities = {}
$.each(data, function (i, n) {

    // set property
    if (!entities[n[0]]) {
        entities[n[0]] = {
            data : {
                n[1]: n[2]
            },
            entity_meta: {
                start: n[1],
                end: n[1]
                min: n[1]
                max: n[1]
            }
        }

    // update property
    } else {

        // add new data property
        entities[n[0]]['data'][n[1]] = n[2];

        // if the property should change then update it
        if ( entities[n[0]]['entity_meta']['min'] > n[1] ) {
             entities[n[0]]['entity_meta']['min'] = n[1];
        }
    }
});
```

That obviously isn't all the code but it should explain clearly the approach that should be taken.

Also not that your intended **final** object structure is very much **over complicated** you should really use arrays where appropriate, especially for `entities` and `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery AJAX to get the CSV file.

```
$.get("test_csv.csv", function(result){
    csvParseAndCalc(result);
});
```

Use a simple JavaScript to parse the CSV and perform the calculations

```
// assumes your sample data is how all data will look
// proper csv parsing (by the spec) is not used is favor is speed
function csvParseAndCalc(result) {
var entities = {};
var indicator_meta = {"start":null, "end":null, "min":null, "max":null};
var rows = result.split('\n'); //your data doesnt need proper (to spec) csv parsing
// run calculations ignore header row
for(var i=1; i<rows.length; i++) {
    var r = rows[i].split(',');
    var id = r[0];
    var yr = parseInt(r[1]);
    var val = parseInt(r[2]);
    var entity = entities[id];
    var edata;
    var emeta;
    // create entity if it doesn't exist
    if(entity == null) {
        entities[id] = { "data": {}, "entity_meta": {"start":null, "end":null, "min":null, "max":null} };
        entity = entities[id];
    }
    // entity data
    edata = entity.data;
    edata[yr] = val;
    // entity meta
    emeta = entity.entity_meta
    if(emeta.start == null || emeta.start > yr) emeta.start = yr;
    if(emeta.end == null || emeta.end < yr) emeta.end = yr;
    if(emeta.min == null || emeta.min > val) emeta.min = val;
    if(emeta.max == null || emeta.max < val) emeta.max = val;
    // calc indicator_meta
    if(indicator_meta.start==null || indicator_meta.start > yr)
        indicator_meta.start = yr;
    if(indicator_meta.end==null || indicator_meta.end < yr)
        indicator_meta.end = yr;
    if(indicator_meta.min==null || indicator_meta.min > val)
        indicator_meta.min = val;
    if(indicator_meta.max==null || indicator_meta.max < val)
        indicator_meta.max = val;
}
// fill gaps on entity data
for(var id in entities) {
    var entity = entities[id];
    var emeta = entity.entity_meta;
    var edata = entity.data;
    for(var i=emeta.start + 1; i<emeta.end; i++) {
        if(edata[i] == null) edata[i] = edata[i-1];
    }
}
return {"population": {"entities":entities, "indicator_meta":indicator_meta} };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, YUI would be helpful for some bulk operations. http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/dataschema/dataschema-text.html

Answer (score 1):

There are javascript sql database libraries.  TaffyDB comes to mind.